# How to declare variable's name by using other variable's string?

Tags: lua

```
function defineVarByString(variableName)
variableName = 123
end

defineVarByString("Hello")

-- Expected Result: Hello = 123
-- Real Output: variableName = 123
```

Could you turn this function into working function? I wanna do it myself but the language barrier doesn't let me learn about metatable and _G and _ENV...

In that case, I can just write 'Hello = 123'. But in actual case, for some reason I need to define many Variable's name by many unexpectable strings.

Comment: You want to create global variables this way? What version of lua?

Comment: @Etan Reisner Yes. Lua 5.1

Comment: Then `_ENV` doesn't exist and metatables don't apply (or at least you don't need to care about them). Have you tried anything here?

Comment: @Etan Reisner I'm very new to Lua. Sadly all I can try was that stupid function only

Comment: http://www.lua.org/pil/14.1.html

Comment: @Etan Reisner What a nice. It's too good. o my.gofd z Thank you. Guess that link says exactly what i want. Now I just wonder how do i understand it. z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function DynamicVariable(VarName)
_G[VarName] = 123
end

DynamicVariable('Hello')
print(Hello)

-- Output => 123
```

More information: http://www.lua.org/pil/14.1.html